# App rendering so ugly

Tags: app

after deploy my sharepoint hosted app. The app rendering so ugly, can you guys explain and tell me what to do with this.[image]

Comment: what browser are you using ? Did you try clearing the browser cache. Check if you are getting any javascript errors in the Console of the browser

Comment: I don't know why, but after I create Web Part Client and deploy it again, it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing CSS, on your default.aspx add the following script to the head if it's missing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';

    // Set the style of the client web part page to be consistent with the host web.
    (function () {
        var hostUrl = '';
        if (document.URL.indexOf('?') != -1) {
            var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var p = decodeURIComponent(params[i]);
                if (/^SPHostUrl=/i.test(p)) {
                    hostUrl = p.split('=')[1];
                    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + hostUrl + '/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx" />');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (hostUrl == '') {
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/themable/corev15.css" />');
        }
    })();
</script>
```